# Google Drive Unresolved Imports

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I am trying to compile Stephen Wylie's example code for Google Drive integration:

```
package com.googledrive.googledriveapp;
// For Google Drive / Play Services
// Version 1.1 - Added new comments & removed dead code
// Stephen Wylie - 10/20/2012
import android.accounts.Account;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.app.Activity;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.BearerToken;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android2.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android2.auth.GoogleAccountManager;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveRequest;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button btn_drive;
    private Context ctx = this;
    private Activity a = this;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        /*
         * Etc... (Other application logic belonging in onCreate)
         */
            btn_drive.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                chooseAccount();
            }
            });
    }

    public void chooseAccount() {
        Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, new String[]{"com.google"}, false, null, null, null, null);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CHOOSE_ACCOUNT);
    }

    // Fetch the access token asynchronously.
    void getAndUseAuthTokenInAsyncTask(Account account) {
        AsyncTask<Account, String, String> task = new AsyncTask<Account, String, String>() {
            ProgressDialog progressDlg;
            AsyncTask<Account, String, String> me = this;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                progressDlg = new ProgressDialog(ctx, ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                progressDlg.setMax(100);
                progressDlg.setTitle("Validating...");
                progressDlg.setMessage("Verifying the login data you entered...\n\nThis action will time out after 10 seconds.");
                progressDlg.setCancelable(false);
                progressDlg.setIndeterminate(false);
                progressDlg.setOnCancelListener(new android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface d) {
                        progressDlg.dismiss();
                        me.cancel(true);
                    }
                });
                progressDlg.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Account... params) {
                return getAccessToken(params[0]);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                if (s == null) {
                    // Wait for the extra intent
                } else {
                    MyApp.accountName = s;
                    getDriveFiles();
                }
                progressDlg.dismiss();
            }
        };
        task.execute(account);
    }

    /**
     * Fetches the token from a particular Google account chosen by the user.  DO NOT RUN THIS DIRECTLY.  It must be run asynchronously inside an AsyncTask.
     * @param activity
     * @param account
     * @return
     */
    private String getAccessToken(Account account) {
        try {
            return GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(ctx, account.name, "oauth2:" + DriveScopes.DRIVE_READONLY);  // IMPORTANT: DriveScopes must be changed depending on what level of access you want
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
            // Start the Approval Screen intent, if not run from an Activity, add the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.
            a.startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_TOKEN);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private Drive getDriveService() {
        HttpTransport ht = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();             // Makes a transport compatible with both Android 2.2- and 2.3+
        JacksonFactory jf = new JacksonFactory();                            // You need a JSON parser to help you out with the API response
        Credential credential = new Credential(BearerToken.authorizationHeaderAccessMethod()).setAccessToken(MyApp.accountName);
        HttpRequestFactory rf = ht.createRequestFactory(credential);
        Drive.Builder b = new Drive.Builder(ht, jf, null);
        b.setJsonHttpRequestInitializer(new JsonHttpRequestInitializer() {

            @Override
            public void initialize(JsonHttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                DriveRequest driveRequest = (DriveRequest) request;
                driveRequest.setPrettyPrint(true);
                driveRequest.setOauthToken(MyApp.accountName);
            }
        });
        return b.build();
    }

    /**
     * Obtains a list of all files on the signed-in user's Google Drive account.
     */
    private void getDriveFiles() {
        Drive service = getDriveService();
        Log.d("SiteTrack", "FUNCTION getDriveFiles()");
        Files.List request;
        try {
            request = service.files().list(); // .setQ("mimeType=\"text/plain\"");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        do {
            FileList files;
            try {
                Log.d("SiteTrack", request.toString());
                files = request.execute();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("SiteTrack", "Exception");
                return;
            }
            List<File> fileList = files.getItems();
            Log.d("SiteTrack", "Files found: " + files.getItems().size());
            for (File f : fileList) {
                String fileId = f.getId();
                String title = f.getTitle();
                Log.d("SiteTrack", "File " + fileId + ": " + title);
            }
            request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
        } while (request.getPageToken() != null && request.getPageToken().length() >= 0);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CHOOSE_ACCOUNT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            MyApp.accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
            GoogleAccountManager gam = new GoogleAccountManager(this);
            getAndUseAuthTokenInAsyncTask(gam.getAccountByName(MyApp.accountName));
            Log.d("SiteTrack", "CHOOSE_ACCOUNT");
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_TOKEN && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            MyApp.accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
            Log.d("SiteTrack", "REQUEST_TOKEN");
        }
    }   
}
```

However, I am getting "cannot be resolved" errors on all the com.google imports. I have Google APIs 16 and have set it as my project build target. Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Robert  what is JacksonFactory() ?? i have error in this code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on Android with GoogleAccountCredential.newChooseAccountIntent()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384236/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-on-android-with-googleaccountcredential-newchoose)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To take care of the Drive-related imports, you'll need a few jars from the [Google Drive SDK](https://code.google.com/p/google-drive-sdk-samples/source/browse/#hg%2Fjava%2Fwar%2FWEB-INF%2Flib). There are a few large ones, so you may want to add them individually to suit your app.

If that doesn't resolve the `com.google.android.gms.*` imports, the Google Play Services add-on needs to be installed (from Extras -> Google Play Services in the SDK Manager) and `google-play-services.jar` needs to be [added to your build path](https://developers.google.com/android/google-play-services/#downloading).

**EDIT**:

In this case, the following jars were needed:

1. google-api-services-drive-v2-rev1-1.7.2-beta.jar
2. google-http-client-1.10.3-beta.jar
3. google-http-client-android2-1.10.3-beta.jar
4. google-oauth-client-1.10.1-beta.jar
5. google-api-client-android2-1.10.3-beta.jar
6. google-api-client-1.10.3-beta.jar

If you're using the Google Plugin for Eclipse, the steps for creating a Drive-enabled project are outlined [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android#step_3_create_and_configure_an_android_project).

Comment: Thanks. Had to import 6 different jar files - surprisingly disorganized on Google's part.

Comment: Perhaps list the jars here to help those who follow?

Comment: 1.google-api-services-drive-v2-rev1-1.7.2-beta.jar            2.google-http-client-1.10.3-beta.jar                        3.google-http-client-android2-1.10.3-beta.jar                4.google-oauth-client-1.10.1-beta.jar                       5.google-api-client-android2-1.10.3-beta.jar                6.google-api-client-1.10.3-beta.jar

Comment: How to download google-api-services-drive-v2-rev1-1.7.2-beta.jar, I have tried a lot for service jar but there is no download link on google?

Comment: @kirtiavaiya Please check the first link ("Google Drive SDK") in my answer. The jars can be downloaded from there.

Comment: @acj but there is no any download link, And in my comment there is clear download link for all jars

Comment: @kirtiavaiya If you click an individual file link, you can then click "View raw file" to download it.

Comment: @acj yes ,you are right but my link will give all the jar as one .zip file,user don't need to download each jar