# GoogleAccountCredential include File

Tags: java, android, google-api, android-studio, google-play-services

I recently updated several libraries using the Android SDK Manager and Android Studio. One of my imports is now failing:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential;
```

I am wondering what package/library this is supposed to be found in so that I can make sure that is being included in the build path, or so that I can revert to an older version.

I am using Android Studio 1.6.0_45

Comment: Jason post here would help you   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384236/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-on-android-with-googleaccountcredential-newchoose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was in:
google-api-client-android-1.15.0-rc.jar